# send and receive at the same time in arduino to xbee

Tags: c, arduino, xbee

I have tried to run the example programs from arduino-xbee library. I need to send some data to a node from a node and at the same time need to be ready to read the data available to the sending node itself. Assuming X sends a data to Y. When Y receives data it sends an acknowledgement back to X.But if Z sends data to X or if Z sends a broadcast will I be able to read the data from Z at X and read the acknowledgement from Y to X.
So any pointers to send and receive at the same time using arduino-xbee would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If arduino-xbee uses "API mode" for the XBee modules, you'll receive separate frames of data.  Each frame will have headers to identify the source of the data, and to match responses to requests (for AT commands).

An XBee module in "AT mode" or "Transparent mode" will just stream data out of the serial port that was received over the network on a specific endpoint and cluster.  You won't know who sent it, and you need to enter "command mode" to read or write parameters using AT commands.